# Authorization error with pengwynn linkedin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linkedin-api

I would like to point out I am a newbie, and not a dev so I might miss some basic step here.

I am trying to figure out how to authorize through omniauth-linkedin gem and query Linkedin API through pengwynn 'linkedin' gem.

I can connect the user through oauth, create the devise-user entry and so on, all good there.

The problems arise when I try to query the API, specifically I would be interested in getting the list of skill for the user. I have this code under my users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    token = @user.access_token
    secret = @user.access_secret

    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"])
    client.authorize_from_access(token, secret)
    raise client
  end
```

I am raising the client just to have a play with the newly created client, unfortunately when querying client.profileI get 401 error:

LinkedIn::Errors::UnauthorizedError: (401): [unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Before of `raise client` you should provide the permissions. You should make a redirect to:

```
redirect_to request_token.authorize_url
```

For example:

```
def show
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"])
  request_token = client.request_token({:oauth_callback => "callback url here"}, :scope => "rw_nus r_fullprofile r_emailaddress")
  client.authorize_from_access(request_token.token, request_token.secret)
  redirect_to request_token.authorize_url
end
```

In your callback url you should save the tokens for future requests.

Good Luck!